# Determining the time complexity of this portion of code

Tags: big-o

```
//Assume these 2 arrays were given to us by the user and we don't know 
// its contents
int A[5] = {1,0,2,1,0};   // (1) operation
int y[5] = {0,0,1,1,2};   // (1)

int n = 5; // (1)
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){   // (n) operations
    if(A[i]!= y[i]){      // is this (n) operations in worst case..?
        cout << "hello" << endl; // is this (n) operations in worst case?
    }
 }
```

I am confused with nested statements, we know that the for loop occurs "n" times and is proportional to the input size. However, the if statement is also proportional to "n" in this case as well? The cout statement is also proportional to "n". Does this mean this piece of code has a running time of O(n^3)..? I am really confused with what is a constant operation and what isn't in terms of proportionality to input size.. I am assuming the worst case here where no items match..

Comment: No, it is not n^3. It can be something like O(2*n) = O(n), but not n^3

Comment: In the worst case, how would I give a number to quantify the number of times the if statement occurs. Is it merely 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just calculate this like:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    if(A[i]!= y[i]){      
        cout << "hello" << endl
    }
}
```

You can say that this `if(A[i]!= y[i])` is one operation with complexity O(1) and in worst case it will be executed n times, but only once in each iteration. Same for `cout`.

So you get 2 constant operations in each iteration. This is

```
O(n)*(O(1) + O(1)) = O(2*n) = O(n)
```